# Check whether date falls in the date range of the current year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Suppose i have an input start date as "01/01/2014" and input end date as "31/01/2014". I need to check whether the input start date and input end date  falls within highlighted record.In the highlighted record i have two columns **monthfrom** and **monthto**.Which is from December to February.But in my table there is no year mentioned.I need to take for current year but if i take current year then my query fails

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '28/02/2014'
```

If i take end date as next year also again my query fails

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '28/02/2015'.
```

Suppose i format the highlighted details as above query then i can check the input date falls within the date range.After checking the input date falls in the highlighted record i need to get number of days using **weekfrom** and **weekto** column.If i use this query
`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '28/02/2015'`.
then will get wrong result because weekfrom will be different in the current year and next year.

Suppose i use the query like this 
`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '28/02/2014'`.Again i will not get the expected result because am checking for December to February of the current year.Please help me i need to check two conditions

1. Whether input date falls in the highlighted record
2. Count the number of days if it falls within the highlighted record with **weekfrom** and **weekto** keeping into consideration.
3. Week from and weekto may be in reverse order also as saturday to sunday(7 to 1).Here also we need to count the number of working days.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN '01/12/2014' AND '28/02/2014'
```

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE dateformatted BETWEEN #01/12/2014# AND #28/02/2014#
```

Comment: Above query is giving the error as Incorrect syntax near '#'.

Comment: Ah i see. You're using varchar for the date field?